# Is there a way to "subscribe" to an array variable changes in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, debouncing

I'm looking for a way to wait for the user to stop interaction and then make an HTTP request, for this I'm looking into the `debounceTime()` operator from RxJs, but the target I'm waiting for is an array I defined.

This is the scenario:

```
export class KeywordSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private proposalService: ProposalService) { }

  @ViewChild(MatTable, {static: true}) kwTable: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @Input() proposalId: string;

  keywordInput = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Keyword>;
  displayedColumns = ['action', 'keyword', 'searches', 'competition', 'cpc'];
  suggestedKeywords: Keyword[] = [];
  selectedKeywords: string[] = [];

  fetchSuggestions(seeds?: string[]) {
    const ideas = {
      seeds: [],
      limit: 25
    };
    this.proposalService.getKeywordIdeas(this.proposalId, ideas).pipe(retry(3)).subscribe(res => {
      this.suggestedKeywords = res;
    });
  }

}
```

I'm not including the whole component here, but the idea is the following:

I have a list of `suggestedKeywords` which I render on the page, each of these should call an `addKeyword()` method to add that keyword to the `dataSource`, and after that, I call the `fetchSuggestions()` method to get new keywords to populate the `suggestedKeywords` list.

The problem comes when I try to select multiple keywords in quick succession, since that would trigger a request for each of those clicks to update the `suggestedKeywords` list, so I wanted to use the `debounceTime()` to prevent the request to trigger until the user stops clicking items for a bit; however this requires an Observable to be the element changing as far as I know, but in my case, it is just a simple array.

**Is there someway to keep track of the value of the array so it waits for a while after it changes before making the HTTP request, like an Observable?**

**EDIT**: Used the `from()` operator as suggested in the comments, in order to actually listen to changes do I need to define other methods? I'm thinking something similar to `valueChanges()` in `FormControls`.

Going through more documentation I'm leaning towards `Subject`, `BehaviorSubject`, etc; but I'm not sure if this would be a correct approach, could anyone provide an example on how to do this?

Comment: Did you tried converting array with  from([]) operator to observable?

Comment: @Bozhinovski didn't know that was a thing, I'll try it out to see if it works for me

Comment: I hope that helps you bud. Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using a `Subject` to keep track of the changes, calling it's `next()` function evrytime a modified the `suggestedKeywords` array and subscribing to it as an observable.

My component ended up looking like this:

```
export class KeywordSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private proposalService: ProposalService) { }

  keywordInput = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
  suggestedKeywords: Keyword[] = [];
  selectedKeywords: string[] = [];
  isLoadingResults = false;

  tag$ = new Subject<string[]>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tag$.asObservable().pipe(
      startWith([]),
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap(seeds => this.getSuggestionsObservable(seeds))
    ).subscribe(keywords => {
      this.suggestedKeywords = keywords;
    });
  }

  addSuggestedKeyword(keyword: Keyword) {
    const suggestedKeyword = keyword;
    const existing = this.dataSource.data;

    if (!existing.includes(suggestedKeyword)) {
      existing.push(suggestedKeyword);
      this.dataSource.data = existing;
    }

    this.tag$.next(this.getCurrentTableKeywords());
  }

  fetchKeywordSearch(keyword: string) {
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.keywordInput.disable();
    const search = {
      type: 'adwords',
      keyword
    };
    const currentData = this.dataSource.data;

    this.proposalService.getKeywordSearch(this.proposalId, search).pipe(retry(3)).subscribe(res => {
      currentData.push(res);
      this.dataSource.data = currentData;
    }, error => {},
    () => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.keywordInput.enable();
      this.tag$.next(this.getCurrentTableKeywords());
    });
  }

  getCurrentTableKeywords(): string[] {}

  getSuggestionsObservable(seeds: string[] = []): Observable<Keyword[]> {
    const ideas = {
      type: 'adwords',
      seeds,
      limit: 25
    };

    return this.proposalService.getKeywordIdeas(this.proposalId, ideas).pipe(retry(3));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your array in Observable.of() RxJS operator and it will behave like observable

Comment: When you say "behave" like observable, to what extent do you mean that? I've tried it, but I'm guessing the part of *notifying when the value has changed* is up to me? Do you have any idea for how I should go about that?

Comment: Then you can set your array in BehaviorSubject variable still will behave like observable, and when new values are received you can emit them